# Error when trying to access regular object property inside sqlite serialize (node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, undefined

When using `db.serialize()` from the *sqlite3* module ([sqlite3 on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3)) I get an error for accessing an object property which is not a problem outside the 'db.serialize()` call.

**Code in question:**

```
var files = [];
var fragments = {};

// [...]

function massInsertIntoDB() {
    // This works fine...
    console.log('Files length: ', files.length);
    console.log('Fragments length: ', Object.keys(fragments).length);

    db.serialize(() => {
        // Still works fine
        console.log('Files length: ', files.length);

        // -----------------
        // ERROR
        // -----------------
        console.log('Fragments length: ', Object.keys(fragments).length);
        // [...]
    });
}
```

**Console output:**

```
Files length:  292582
Fragments length:  20242
Files length:  292582

/Users/Jonas/dev/electron-projects/tag-file-search/file-search/sqlite-insert-and-search.js:78
    console.log('Fragments length: ', Object.keys(fragments).length);
                                         ^

TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.keys (native)
    at Database.<anonymous> (/Users/Jonas/dev/electron-projects/tag-file-search/file-search/sqlite-insert-and-search.js:78:46)
    at massInsertIntoDB (/Users/Jonas/dev/electron-projects/tag-file-search/file-search/sqlite-insert-and-search.js:75:6)
    at Interface.<anonymous> (/Users/Jonas/dev/electron-projects/tag-file-search/file-search/sqlite-insert-and-search.js:195:3)
    at emitNone (events.js:72:20)
    at Interface.emit (events.js:166:7)
    at Interface.close (readline.js:285:8)
    at ReadStream.onend (readline.js:94:10)
    at emitNone (events.js:72:20)
    at ReadStream.emit (events.js:166:7)
```

I have no idea why this doesn't work, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what do you have inside files and fragments objects? Can you please provide the content of files and fragments objects?

Comment: fragments is just an object mapping strings to numbers, files contains little objects (three items). I solved it by moving all code that wasn't a loop or a db... call out of db.serialize() and now it works. Perhaps the sqlite3 module works with an older JS version and thus does not support Object.keys yet? Could that be possible?